# Javascript object reference pattern

Tags: javascript, performance, closures

I have one object:

```
var callback = {
    onValueChange: function () { },
    onTabPressed: function () { },
    onFocus: function () { }
};
```

On my page, i have different editors, like `textEditor` and `numericEditor`, and i bind them separately:

```
function bindEditors() {
    var editors = $(".editor");
    editors.each(function (i) {
        var editor = $(this);
        var editorType = editor.attr("data-editorType");

        if (editorType == "textEditor") {
            bindTextEditor(editor);

        } else if (editorType == "numericEditor") {
            bindNumericEditor();
        }
    });
};
function bindTextEditor(editor) {
    editor.bind("change", function () {
        // calculate value
        callback.onValueChange($(this), value);
    });
};
function bindNumericEditor(editor) {
    editor.bind("change", function () {
        // calculate value
        callback.onValueChange($(this), value);
    });
};
```

My question is:

Is ok to keep `callback` object outside of the binding functions? Wouldn't each binding function create a copy of the `callback` object? (which uses extra memory)

Or should i pass the `callback` object as a parameter to each of the binding functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't create copies of the enclosed object, just references to the same object, so I wouldn't worry about that. And I definitely wouldn't pass callback as a parameter.

I don't think there's anything crazily wrong with what you wrote, but if you wanted to cut down on your code's complexity, you could just bind it once and do the switch inside the binding itself:

```
$(".editor").bind("change", function(){
  var editor = $(this);
  var editorType = editor.attr("data-editorType");

  if (editorType == "textEditor") {
    //calculate value
  } else if (editorType == "numericEditor") {
    //calculate value
  }

  callback.onValueChange(editor, value);
});
```

That probably doesn't perform any differently, but it's cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

1) Is ok to keep callback object outside of the binding functions?

Absolutely!

2) Wouldn't each binding function create a copy of the callback object?

No.

3) Or should i pass the callback object as a parameter to each of the binding functions?
No.